# How to make GridView empty?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have a GridView and am displaying results by search button. For the first search it works fine, but when I click on second search, even if that search result does not exist, the old data is still displayed.

How can I make the GridView empty if there is no result found?

I used LINQ to SQL concept to display the search results.

Comment: @All.. i tried to put <emptydatatemplate> in grid vew, as <emptydatatemplate>No results found</emptydatatemplate>. this works fine..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to assign `null` as DataSource and then rebind the gridview e.g.

```cs
yourGridViewId.DataSource = null;
yourGridViewId.DataBind();
```

Comment: @Muhammad.. i tried to put <emptydatatemplate> in grid vew, as <emptydatatemplate>No results found</emptydatatemplate>. this works fine..is it correct way?

Comment: @Mihir, I have not checked this, but you can test and if it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

"emptydatatemplate" works better in my case:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelGrilla" CssClass="scrollable"  Height="350px" ScrollBars="Vertical">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridAcc" CssClass="cgrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
        <emptydatatemplate>No data found</emptydatatemplate>
        <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```